# Running ubuntu 15.04 on Lenovo T440p, built in display is not turning on

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, display

This has been working fine, I was using the built in display Saturday night without any issues. I then didn't do anything and come Monday morning when I got to work the display did not turn on. I have two other external displays connected and they are working.

Observations:

The built in display is not reporting anything. It does not display the bios or the splash screen. I understand that this may sound like a hardware issue, I want to see if there is anything software wise that I could try before ruling out the software.

What I have tried:

I have rebooted the laptop a few times.

System Settings > Displays, click on Built in Display which is turned off, I then turn it on and click Apply, it asks me if I want to keep the changes and I click Keep This Configuration, though nothing has changed. I leave the displays settings and go back to it and the Built in Display is turned off again.

```
jtoscarson@jtoscarson-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4000 x 2560, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1600x900       60.0 +
1440x900       59.9  
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1152x864       60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9
```

This is the output for the built in display from xrandr.